# How can I integrate Magento into an existing website via Cpanel and show the base URL?

Tags: integrate

I installed Magento but now all magento things are located at /magento/. I don't want "magento" to be in the URL, and I need to be able to integrate Magento with my existing PHP-based website (no frameworks like wordpress - my website is purely PHP).

For example, I need to have an "add to cart" button on my website and have it add to cart even though I am on MY WEBSITE not within the magento subdirectory; and also to be able to display my cart in a sidebar section ON MY WEBSITE which is below the /magento/ subfolder (my website is in the root).

Further, do I need HTTPS?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get rid of 'magento' in the url, you can either install magento directly in the document root, but keep in mind that magento has it's own `index.php` and that might override your `index.php`.  You can overcome this by making your homepage be something else than `index.php`.

Or you can leave it like that and do some redirects from `.htaccess`, but this can be a little complicated. I have no idea how they would look like because I don't know how is your website structured.

As for https...this depends. It's nice to have to make the customers feel safe when entering personal data, but is not mandatory for the website to function.

---

And stop calling wordpress a framework. It is merely a collection of badly written functions :)